# Demographics on Bitcoin users?

Tags: user-base

Speaking with a large group about Bitcoins lately, I noticed that most people there came to like Bitcoins for different reasons. The shady ppl wanted drugs, the accountants wanted to avoid taxes, the Ron Paul people wanted more personal liberty and to end the Fed, The traders wanted new Forex opportunities, and the computer techies were in love with the elegance of the system...

So I'm really starting to wonder here, What are the demographics of the Bitcoin users? Has anyone attempted to do a serious attempt at finding those? Perhaps even a big website poll?

Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: direct analysis of the blockchain:
http://getaddr.bitnodes.io/

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any known data about real demographics.

But here are some things you can consider to get an idea:

- [BitcoinCharts' currency distribution](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/volumepie/): Gives you a view on what currencies are traded the most, most currencies are country- or region-specific so this can be a measure.
- [BlockChain.info's real-time transaction mapping](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions?format=webgl): You can literally see every new transmitted transaction appear on the map. (This is possible because all transactions are public and have an IP bound to them. But note that some users might use Bitcoin with tools like [Tor](http://www.torproject.org) so their location can be wrong.)

Comment: There's no IP address bound to a transaction.  BlockChain.info just reports the IP of the first peer that relayed each transaction to them, and since they connect to a lot of peers, it's more likely that's the IP of the originating peer.  But if I don't accept connections from BlockChain.info and don't connect to them myself, they'll never see my IP on my transactions.

Answer (score 1):

A recent survey solicited to BitcoinTalk forum members:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=88927.0

Answer (score 0):

There was a Bitcoin survey recently: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=88927.0.